# Android using front camera - compatibility for all devices

Tags: android, camera, device, compatibility, using

I have used this script to open front face camera:

```
private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread() {
int cameraCount = 0;
Camera cam = null;
Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
    Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
    if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        try {
            cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I think this script should select and open the front camera on all devices. 
But on my devices is script working properly only on device with two cameras (front + back camera). On other device with one front camera I receive only blank screen. Is there any difference to access to camera with one front camera only ?

Answer (score 1):

> *"On other device with one front camera I receive only blank screen."*

By *"receiv[ing] only blank screen"*, do you mean from the [Camera Preview](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html#camera-preview)? Opening camera by calling `Camera.open(cameraId)` does not automatically give you the preview screen. Please refer to `startPreview()` method from [this](http://boundarydevices.com/how-to-write-an-android-camera-app/) sample tutorial for an example of starting camera preview.

In addition, make sure your device doesn't have any hardware issues (confirm your codes by testing on stock-camera app to see if successfully opens camera preview or on different devices).

> *"But on my devices is script working properly only on device with two
>   cameras (front + back camera)."*

The values of `camIdx` and `cameraCount` are valid and as intended; therefore, it should be working properly. Regardless of the total number of the camera that device has, the code you provided in your question *only* opens front camera,  Evaluating your code:

**If you have one camera:**

```
cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); // cameraCount == 1
// in for loop
cam = Camera.open(camIdx); // camIdx == 0
```

**If you have two cameras:**

```
cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); // cameraCount == 2
// ... more codes
// in for loop
cam = Camera.open(camIdx); // camIdx == 1
```

> *"Is there any difference to access to camera with one front camera only ?"**

There shouldn't be any difference in calling [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) object and its associated methods when dealing with different devices with different specs. As far as Android application development is concerned, all we need is to retrieve `Camera.CameraInfo` object by calling `Camera.CameraInfo()` and to call its associated methods when needed.

Answer (score 0):

This method should give you the most front camera available.  If the device only has a rear camera, you'll get that one.  If there are two, you'll get the front one.  If there's just one on the front, you'll get that one:

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        // get the front-est camera
        c = Camera.open(Camera.getNumberOfCameras() - 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get the camera");
    }
    return c;
}
```